# Disable caching on x86_64

Tags: linux

I tried to disable caching by adding an uncachable region in /proc/mtrr but it seems that sometimes it works and sometimes it cannot. I have to readd the whole region again, it works, for ex:

My add:

```
reg00: base=0x000000000 (    0MB), size= 16384MB, count=1: write-back
reg01: base=0x400000000 (16384MB), size=  8192MB, count=1: write-back
reg03: base=0x020000000 ( 8192MB), size=   512MB, count=1: uncachable
```

I have to disable reg00 and then add again the region base from 0x000000000 as uncachable region:

```
reg00: base=0x000000000 (    0MB), size= 16384MB, count=1: uncachable
reg01: base=0x400000000 (16384MB), size=  8192MB, count=1: write-back
```

Now it can work but the system is very slow. Is any other way to disable cache on x86? As I know on arm architecture, Linux supports a configuration CONFIG_CPU_DCACHE_DISABLE to support cache disable but I do not find the same on x86.

Comment: I'd rather expect things to be slow when you disable caching. Why do you believe that a different way of disabling caching would be faster? (Also, what are you trying to accomplish?)

Comment: Hi, I do not mean another caching way does not cause system slowly. I just mean that caching through /proc/mtrr sometimes is not successful. I just want to reserve a physical memory region and do not want CPU cache to test my driver.

Comment: That's a very common problem for drivers to have when they implement DMA operations. Look at how that's handled in the kernel.